# Sharing shiny application as webpage

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, deploying

I want to deploy the  shiny app as a webpage with this command line 
`runApp(shinyApp(ui, server), host="0.0.0.0" , port = 3994 ,launch.browser = TRUE)`
But i got this error when running the app

> Error in runApp(app) : Can't call `runApp()` from within `runApp()`. If your application code contains `runApp()`, please remove it.

The thing is there isn't an other runApp command 
and i can run the App with :
`app <- shinyApp(ui, server)`

Comment: Have you tried just `runApp("path/to/dir", ...)`? The first argument to `runApp` is `appDir`, the path to the application to run, whereas the return value of `shinyApp` is: *"An object that represents the app. Printing the object or passing it to 'runApp()' will run the app."*

Comment: @r2evans Thank you sir for you reply i will check this solution in see if it's working